# geometry's bindingoffset seems to be ignored

Tags: margins, geometry, lengths

The `geometry`'s documentation tells:

- page 9: "`bindingoffset` removes a specified space from the lefthand-side of the page for oneside or the inner-side for twoside.",
- page 10 (caption of Figure 6): "The option `bindingoffset` adds the specified length to the inner margin. ".

This seems to be contradictory and, from line 748 of the code:

```
\advance\oddsidemargin\Gm@bindingoffset
```

I guess `bindingoffset` **adds** the specified length to the inner (left) margin.

Anyway, `bindingoffset` seems to be ignored as shown by the following MWE: if `bindingoffset > 0`, the effective length of the left margin (shown by the page grid) is the `left` length (that is `oddsidemargin + 1 inch`, here `31mm`) and not the `left` + `bindingoffset` length (here `41mm`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[step=5mm]{pagegrid}
\usepackage{printlen}
\usepackage{geometry}
%
\uselengthunit{mm}
%
\geometry{%
  paperwidth=15cm
  ,showframe
  ,verbose
  ,bindingoffset=1cm
}
%
\newlength{\leftplusoneinch}
\newlength{\leftplusoneinchplusbindingoffset}
%
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\setlength{\leftplusoneinch}{\oddsidemargin+1in}
\setlength{\leftplusoneinchplusbindingoffset}{\leftplusoneinch+\Gm@bindingoffset}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  bindingoffset                 & $=\printlength{\Gm@bindingoffset}$                 \\
  left (oddsidemargin + 1 inch) & $=\printlength{\leftplusoneinch}$                  \\
  left + bindingoffset          & $=\printlength{\leftplusoneinchplusbindingoffset}$ 
\end{tabular}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Hence my question: why `geometry`'s `bindingoffset` seems to be ignored?

Comment: Use an extreme value of 10cm to better see differences.

Comment: have you tried using `\documentclass[twoside]{article}`? does that help?

Comment: @Johannes_B Well, I better see differences but don't better understand :)

Comment: @cmhughes Yes: in fact I got this MWE from my real document which actually uses the two-sided `book` class. And it's with this class I first encountered the problem. So it doesn't help.